# Node.js upstart vs forever

Tags: node.js, upstart, forever

I am looking to daemonize my Node.js application. What's the difference between upstart and forever? Also, are there other packages I might want to considering looking at?

Comment: You'll probably need to use upstart or some other init script to *start* forever anyway, when your system restarts.

Answer (score 24):

As pointed out in the comments, [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) will be used to start the [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) script, since `upstart` has hooks for system events (like shutdown and startup of your server).

The other differences are:

- Upstart was developed for Linux, while forever is platform-independent.
- Forever is specific to nodejs, and has some pretty cool features with regards to restarting your server after it crashes, and logging.
- Forever is sufficient for development environment, while upstart is necessary if you need to have some control over how your server is stopped. For example, on shutdown, the forever process would simply get killed, but, with an upstart script, you can collect logs and notify the admin.
- Upstart allows you to add other monitoring tools, like [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

Among the available other solutions, you can try [daemon](https://npmjs.org/package/daemon), which is equivalent to forever.

I would disagree with @leorex with regards to upstart setup. Check out [this blog post](https://www.exratione.com/2013/02/nodejs-and-forever-as-a-service-simple-upstart-and-init-scripts-for-ubuntu/) for an excellent example.

Answer (score 1):

upstart is a general utility for daemonizing an application. Forever is designed for Node.js. For most purposes, forever is better for Node.js applications as it is simpler, tuned towards node.js and easy to configure. Just try a few tutorials on upstart and you will agree with me.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference in objective is that upstart is designed to start an application on system boot. Forever doesn't have that and instead is focused on keeping a node.js script running despite crashes (most likely unhandled exceptions). You will be wise to combine the two .. i.e. start `forever yourscript.js` from upstart (on system boot).

That said you will need to look at your platform specific version of `upstart` equivalent. Upstart was never on windows and is now deprecated for ubuntu / debian : http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316

Answer (score 1):

In 2017, alternatives could be :

- [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). Robust, strong community, production-grade solution. Can manage non-node scripts as well. My personal choice.
- [StrongLoop (slc)](https://strongloop.com/). Node-only. Production-oriented as well, includes build/packaging, deployment to docker, load-balancing and profiling, but is more recent. Looks promising.

Here is a (maybe biased) [comparison](http://strong-pm.io/compare/) of both with Forever.

Comment: Wow, pm2 is incredible. Thanks!