# Node JS Http Server Production Ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I am building a simple web service using node js, I only use the built in web server feature using:

```
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
```

I added a caching mechanism using node-cache, but that's it, I run the script via PM2 to make sure it's always running. Is this a safe and good practice to do? I saw some posts mentioning using nginx as reverse proxy server, won't that add an extra step that will slow things down?

Thanks!

Comment: not really sure about using PM2 for keeping the server alive, I would personally prefer to use native OS option, e.g. upstart if you are on Linux. 
As for nginx, it is preferable to have a reverse proxy server for load balancing, data compression, SSL encryption etc.. But obviously nginx is not the only choice.

Comment: @Yerken PM2 is a production ready tool. It starts itself with native OS upstart mechanism. Also it has a lot of plugins.

Comment: `forever` is also good option for production.https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: @PashaRumkin Thanks bud, haven't found myself in need to use it, but should definitely check it out :)

Comment: @MohdSayeed `forever` by itself is not enough, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601399/node-js-upstart-vs-forever

Comment: @Yerken yes there are pros and cons in PM2 and forever https://mrvautin.com/running-nodejs-applications-in-production-forever-vs-supervisord-vs-pm2/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's recomended to use nginx as a frontier in production for secure reasons, load balancing, static content output and administration issues. In some cases it could be used for API versioning.